# pivot_root device or resource busy

Tags: linux

Produces the following command on Ubuntu 64bit on VMWare:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /newroot
cd /newroot
mkdir old-root
pivot_root . old-root
```

I get an error that I do not understand

```
pivot_root: device or resource busy
```

Any ideas?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179788/pivot-root-device-or-resource-busy/275353

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error when the new root directory is a plain directory. When the new root is a mount, it will be ok. A bind mount of a directory is ok too. Also need to make sure the root directory permission is `0755`, and owned by the root user.

The related answer states that you need to umount /proc first. I do not see the same.

The host ubnutu is 16.04 and it pivots into 18.04. Used `unshare -m -p -f /bin/bash`, followed by `pivot_root . old_root`. The `-f` is necessary to avoid a [memory allocation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666700/unshare-pid-bin-bash-fork-cannot-allocate-memory).