# unshare --pid /bin/bash - fork cannot allocate memory

Tags: linux, bash, linux-namespaces

I'm experimenting with linux namespaces.  Specifically the pid namespace.

I thought I'd test something out with bash but run into this problem:

```
unshare -p /bin/bash
bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

Running ls from there gave a core dump.  Exit is the only thing possible.

Why is it doing that?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The error is caused by the PID 1 process exits in the new namespace.

After bash start to run, bash will fork several new sub-processes to do somethings. If you run unshare without -f, bash will have the same pid as the current "unshare" process. The current "unshare" process call the unshare systemcall, create a new pid namespace, but the current "unshare" process is not in the new pid namespace. It is the desired behavior of linux kernel: process A creates a new namespace, the process A itself won't be put into the new namespace, only the sub-processes of process A will be put into the new namespace. So when you run:

```
unshare -p /bin/bash
```

The unshare process will exec /bin/bash, and /bin/bash forks several sub-processes, the first sub-process of bash will become PID 1 of the new namespace, and the subprocess will exit after it completes its job. So the PID 1 of the new namespace exits.

The PID 1 process has a special function: it should become all the orphan processes' parent process. If PID 1 process in the root namespace exits, kernel will panic. If PID 1 process in a sub namespace exits, linux kernel will call the disable_pid_allocation function, which will clean the PIDNS_HASH_ADDING flag in that namespace. When linux kernel create a new process, kernel will call alloc_pid function to allocate a PID in a namespace, and if the PIDNS_HASH_ADDING flag is not set, alloc_pid function will return a -ENOMEM error. That's why you got the "Cannot allocate memory" error.

You can resolve this issue by use the '-f' option:

```
unshare -fp /bin/bash
```

If you run unshare with '-f' option, unshare will fork a new process after it create the new pid namespace. And run /bin/bash in the new process. The new process will be the pid 1 of the new pid namespace. Then bash will also fork several sub-processes to do some jobs. As bash itself is the pid 1 of the new pid namespace, its sub-processes can exit without any problem.

Comment: To back this very helpful answer up with some man page references: [`man 2 unshare`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html) says about `CLONE_NEWPID`: _Unshare the PID namespace, so that the calling process has a new PID namespace for its children which is not shared with any previously existing process.  The calling process is not moved into the new namespace.  **The first child created by the calling process will have the process ID 1** and will assume the role of init(1) in the new namespace._

Comment: " It is the desired behavior of linux kernel: process A creates a new namespace, the process A itself won't be put into the new namespace, only the sub-processes of process A will be put into the new namespace." --- Isnt this statement Trie only for PID namespace? Wouldn't it work with other namespaces like mount?

Comment: @yupeng0921 "unshare -fp /bin/bash", it worked. But after that when I do `ps -e`, I could see all the processes from the host machine. As per the explanation, I should only see the unshare process with PID 1 and some bash processes running. But this is not the case. Could you please explain?

Comment: @AmitBhaira Your `ps` probably works by reading `/proc`, and you still have your parent namespace's `/proc` mounted. Use `--mount-proc`.

Comment: `unshare -pf --mount-proc=/proc /bin/sh` -->   `ls -d /proc/[0-9]*` (Returns 1 process with PID 1)

`unshare -p --mount-proc=/proc /bin/sh` --> `ls -d /proc/[0-9]*` (returns all processes from parent namespace) 

With the second command, you can fork exactly once, so you could call bash there and get on with it, but you won't be using a new process namespace. 

I thought perhaps once you run a new process it would take you in the new process namespace. It seems all other namespaces apply though. Wouldn't it make sense that using the flag p automatically forks by default?

Answer (score 15):

This does not explain *why* this happens, but shows how to correctly launch a shell in a new pid namespace:

Use the `-f` flag to fork off the shell from `unshare`, so that the new shell gets PID 1 in the newly created namespace:

```
unshare -fp /bin/bash
```

You probably also want to pass the `--mount-proc` option, so that your `ps` listing reflects your newly created PID namespace rather than the parent PID namespace:

```
unshare -fp --mount-proc /bin/bash
```

Now run `ps`:

```
# ps
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
11 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: glad to see that it helped!