# Why is bash, when run by unshare, unable to fork any processes?

Tags: linux, namespaces

I am using Arch Linux, and trying to do some experiments about linux namespace. I use the following command but doesn't get bash to work.

```
xtricman⚓ArchVirtual⏺️~unshare -muinpUC --propagation slave --setgroups deny /usr/bin/bash
Could not get property: Access denied
nobody⚓⏺️~ls
bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
nobody⚓⏺️~
```

Then No external commands can be run by the shell, could anybody explain the reason to me?

Comment: The question title is contradicted by the body, which clearly shows the Bourne Again shell running, chained-to from `unshare`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need run `unshare` with `-f`?

See: [unshare --pid /bin/bash - fork cannot allocate memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666700/unshare-pid-bin-bash-fork-cannot-allocate-memory)